# Facebook JavaScript application was working, now suddenly "Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration"

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a bit of a strange problem...

I created an application that has users log in with Facebook, so I set things up in **facebook developers**. In particular, I set my domain under AppDomains and under the Website with Facebook Login.

This was working perfectly well a week ago, however I navigated onto my site today and it is no longer working and is giving the error:

> Given URL is not permitted by the application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.

Has anyone encountered this before? I'm at a loss as to why it could just stop working, since I haven't touched the code since last week.

Comment: Okay... I tried changing my AppDomain to `mywebsite.com` rather than `www.mywebsite.com` - however, I still have no idea why it would be working before for days, and then suddenly stop working after a while? I'm a little concerned. 

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem to this. if your facebook app under facebook developer your app
WEBSITE WITH FACEBOOK LOGIN - SITE URL : http://www.yourdomain.com

When users goes to your website and login via yourdomain.com without www. you will have this error.

Solution will be forcing user to only key with www. here is a piece of php code:

```
$protocol = (@$_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") ? "https://" : "http://";
if (substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, 4) !== 'www.') {
    header('Location: '.$protocol.'www.'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    exit;
}
```

I hope it helps this problem give me 3 days of headache that some user is able to login.